# SQL select invalid because it is not contained in aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here's the problem, I want to display the month, count and avg of one column in a table, but I keep getting an error when I try and group it by the month.

This is the code:

```
SELECT MONTH(ContractDate) AS Q, 
       DATENAME(month, ContractDate) AS M, 
       COUNT(ContractDate) AS C, SUM(ContractPrice) AS S 
       FROM dashboard
       WHERE YEAR(ContractDate) = $year
       AND ContractDate IS NOT NULL
       AND ContractPrice IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY MONTH(ContractDate)
```

But this results in the error:

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]
Column 'dashboard.ContractDate' is invalid in the select 
list because it is not contained in either an aggregate 
function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

But if I removed the `MONTH()` from the group by... it works fine.. But I need to have them grouped by month otherwise I get multiple of the same month not counted as one.

Sorry again, I did search and there is HEAPS of answers, but like I said I'm noob and they didn't really help me because I don't understand why this happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to have all columns that are not aggregates in the `GROUP BY`. Either add your `DATENAME` column into the `GROUP BY` or remove it from the query altogether.

```
GROUP BY MONTH(ContractDate) AS Q, DATENAME(month, ContractDate)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was simple... I guess I've been looking at the code so long I've lost my mind a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing your query after removing `DATENAME(month, ContractDate) AS M`. I guess this is causing the issue. You are doing a `GROUP BY MONTH(ContractDate)` but also trying to use `ContractDate` which is not in the `GROUP BY` list.